# new ATMEGA1281 and avrdude

Tags: avr, atmel, atmega, avrdude

I'm experiencing sometimes problems when programming my new ATMEGA1281. It is suposed to be the same as my old one, the only difference I guess is the serial number:

ATMEGA1281 16AU **1104** vs ATMEGA1281 16AU **1304**

I'm used to program the ATMEGA1281 with avrdude command, but with the new chip, I have sometimes this error:

```
avrdude: verifying ... 
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000 
0x0c != 0xff 
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

Do you know why I'm having this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What programmer do you use?

The brand new microcontroler might have lower clock than your previous one and it might be to slow for your programmer.

Try decreasing your programmer bitclock (`-B` option of `avrdude`). It should be 4 times slower than the  clock. Then you can change microcontroller fuses and use the programmer with the old bitclock.